# selenium not working with chromedriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

My test code is working well with Firefox and IE but its not working with chrome, chrome window opens for a while when I run the test file, it display url in url-bar and in status bar shows message Resolving...

then chrome window is close with test failed.
Same test works perfectly with IE and Firefox.

My chrome version is:  `24.0.1312.57 m`
I used latest drivers from `http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list`
both

```
chromedriver_win_23.0.1240.0.zip
chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0.zip
```

Comment: It is not enough to find the problem. If you get any error log then post it.

Comment: Your version of Selenium is....?

Comment: @coure2011 Hello coure. I am facing similar challenge when i am trying to test an application on ChromDriver. Did you got any solution for this problem?